# Create a JSON object when page load from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json

I'm using a library that uses a JSON array to draw a timeline.

Is possible to create a JSON object via PHP to be used with this library in the moment that the page is loaded? If yes, how I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.  Just echo out the object onto the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
    echo 'var yourObj = ', json_encode($yourObject), ';';
?>
</script>
```